# Displaying user name and user id from $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have been having trouble echoing my `$_SESSION['user_name']`. I noticed that if I delete "!" from the if statement in the form where if logged in or not is determined, it works after the second login:

`if(!isset($_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS'])`

However, despite the fact this makes no sense to me it also disables the logout function, therefore I try to avoid this. I am also wondering if it is an issue with have having the username populated in a separate form.

I am also unable to return any value with `$_SESSION['user_id']`. I have tried many things including checking spell using PDO::FETCH_NUM and verifying my table credentials and still nothing.

As of now the validation works for user name and password but nothing is returned when echoing `$_SESSION['user_name']` and `$_SESSION['user_id']` in the current code:

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('php/config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $username = $_POST['user_name'];
  $password = $_POST['pwd'];

  $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tapp_login WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1");
  $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
  $stmt->store_result();
  if($stmt->num_rows == 1){  //To check if the row exists
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM); //fetching the contents of the row
    $_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS']=true;
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $username;              
    echo 'true';  
  }
  else {
    echo 'false';
  }
  $stmt->close();
}
else{
}
$con->close();
?>
```

FORM:

```
<body>
<fieldset id="login_form_wrap" class="login_form_header">
  <legend><a href='projects.php'>CUSTOMER LOGIN</a></legend>
  <?php session_start();
  $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();?>
  <div id="profile"> 
  <!--If not logged in-->  
  <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS']) || ($_SESSION['timeout'] + 600 < time())){?>
    <div id="login_a">
      <a id="login_profile" href="#">click to login</a>
    </div>
  <!--Else if logged in-->
  <?php }else {;?>
  <a href='logout_session.php' id='logout'>Logout</a>
  <!--header('location: dashboard.php');-->
  <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <form action="login_validation.php" id="login_form" method="POST">
    <div id="login_b">
      <div class="welcome"></div>
      <span class="col1">USER NAME:</span>
      <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" class="input" required />
      <span class="col1">PASSWORD:</span>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="input" required />
      <span class="col1"></span>
      <input type="submit" name"submit" id="login_validation" value="SUBMIT" />
      <input type="reset" id="cancel_hide" value="CANCEL" />
      <div id="add_err"><br></div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <form action="project_validation.php" id="projects_form" method="POST">
  <div id="projects">

    <!-------------------------- Does not work ------------------------->
    <div class="welcome">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name'];?><br>
    User ID: <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?></div>  


    <span class="col1">PROJECTS:</span>
    <select id="Projects" name="Projects" class="input">
    <option id="project" name="project" value="" selected="selected" disabled='disabled'>Choose a Project...</option>

    ...

    </select>  
  </div>
  <span class="col1"></span>          
  <input type="submit" name="select" id="project_validation" value="SELECT" />
  <div id="add_err"><br></div> 
  </form>
</fieldset>
</body>
```

In case your wondering the "..." just represent more of form that is not necessary.

Comment: You need to learn the basics first.

Comment: @relentless maybe so.. I'm new at this, just looking for a point in the right direction.

Comment: I didn't say that to discourage you, I said that because your question is too big to answer here. Keep trying. Read some tutorials, watch videos etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PHP official documention:

> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

In your form page, you call session_start after contents have been sent to the output. You have to call session_start before writting HTML.