# php retain session across pages with redirect

Tags: php, session

My issue is similar to [Displaying user name and user id from $_SESSION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008511/displaying-user-name-and-user-id-from-session)
however, I will try and detail the problem. I am modifying existing code to add "login expiration" and "login page redirection". Both modifications are are in separate include files. The login page redirection works fine if I exclude the login expiration file.

The problem is that `$_SESSION['url']` is set in page_one.php but doesn't retain session in login.php as long as the timeout.php include is active? If I comment out the timeout.php in the requesting page (page_one.php) the session works as designed.

BTW: the session_id is the same in all pages.

Login Expiration (timeout.php):

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || (time() - $_SESSION['login_time'] > 1200)){
header("Location: {$home_url}logout.php");
}
else{
$_SESSION['last_login_time'] = $_SESSION['login_time'];
// reset timer on page refresh 
$_SESSION['login_time'] = time();
}
?>
```

Page Redirection (redirect_login.php):

```
<?php
$_SESSION['url'] = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
```

(login.php):

```
// if access level is 'Admin', redirect to admin section
    if($user->access_level=='Admin'){

        if(isset($_SESSION['url'])) {
            $myurl = $_SESSION['url']."?action=login_success"; 
        }
        else{
            $myurl = $home_url . "admin/index.php?action=login_success";
        }
    header("Location:  {$myurl}");
    }

    // else, redirect only to 'Customer' section
    else{
        header("Location: {$home_url}index.php?action=login_success");
    }
```

(page_one.php):

```
<?php
// *** this contains the session_start() for each page ***
include_once "php-login-system/config/core.php";

include "php-login-system/redirect_login.php";

include_once "php-login-system/admin/login_checker.php";

$page_title="Page One.1";

include_once 'php-login-system/admin/layout_head.php';

// 20 min timer on logged in user. *** Problem if enabled ***
include_once 'php-login-system/timeout.php';

echo "<div class='col-md-12'>";

// get parameter values, and to prevent undefined index notice
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";

if($action=='already_logged_in'){
    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>";
        echo "<strong>You</strong> are already logged in.";
    echo "</div>";
}

else if($action=='logged_in_as_admin'){
    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>";
        echo "<strong>You</strong> are logged in as admin.";
    echo "</div>";
}

echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>";

$logintimestamp = $_SESSION['last_login_time'];
    echo date("H:i:s", $logintimestamp) . "<br>";
$timestamp = time();
    echo date("H:i:s", $timestamp) . "<br>";
    echo ("The session time was just reset from: ". $_SESSION['login_time'] . " to: " . time()); 

echo "</div>";
?>

<div class='alert alert-info'>
login time: <?php echo $_SESSION['login_time']; ?><br>
login id: <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?><br>
login logged T/F: <?php echo $_SESSION['logged_in']; ?><br>
login access level: <?php echo $_SESSION['access_level']; ?><br>
login last name: <?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?><br>
current URL: <?php echo $_SESSION['url']; ?><br>
session id: <?php echo session_id(); ?>
</div>      

<?php
echo "</div>";
include_once 'php-login-system/admin/layout_foot.php';
?>
```

Comment: I haven't fully parsed your question, but if you add `exit;` to any `header('Location: ...');` directive, this should fix at least some bugs (possibly solve your problem entirely).

Comment: can you explain what adding `exit;` will do? How would `exit;` before or after the header have any impact. ending the directive after doesn't make sense?

Comment: You need to add `exit;` immediately after any other call. Otherwise, the PHP script keeps executing. My original comment was unclear, you need to call exit after any `header` redirects.

Comment: still same issue, `$_SESSION['url']` is empty? in login.php

Comment: Is there anything in `$_SESSION`? Did you call `session_start();`? You don't seem to be including `"php-login-system/config/core.php";` in `login.php`

Comment: core.php is there I excluded it to shorten the code. - $_SESSION contains 6 elements of other session data - it contains 7 elements when I test it from the page_one after setting the 'url'

Comment: I can only suggest testing the expressions in `!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || (time() - $_SESSION['login_time'] > 1200)` separately. I don't see your `logout.php` code but I imagine it destroys the sessions, so this expression is likely evaluating to `true`

Comment: yes that is what I have. it seems to work fine, but might have something to do with problem - since if I remove it, the redirect works

Comment: Right. So before you go into the if statement, you could just `echo 'User ID set: ' . !isset($_SESSION['user_id'])` and `echo 'Time: ' . (time() - $_SESSION['login_time']);` and `die;`. It's likely that the second statement is the culprit, but looking at the output will let you know

Comment: I think I may have found the problem: I moved the timeout.php above the layout_head.php (both includes) - since the later generates html, this must have been causing the session problem in my page_one.php

Comment: Ohhh. Yes, any `header` calls need to be done before output is sent. Good catch, congrats! If you need to retain the order of includes, you could always use output buffering, but I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: thanks for the help, this did resolve. redirect and expiring both working...